# What is the the most profitable way of transferring euro to usd in the states?

Tags: money-transfer, international-transfer, usd-us-dollar, cryptocurrency

What is the the most profitable way of transferring euro to usd in the states. First answer it by bank transfer. I guess there would be a lot of fees. Another way i guess is through bitcoin since it is universal but i do not know how safe this is and how you can transform money credit to bitcoins and vice versa. Recently i read about stellar network which provices transactions in multi-currency system through gateways that receive credit in a currency and transform it in a stellar.

Comment: The question as it stands is unclear and primarily opinion based and may be closed. Could you edit this and make it more specific use case you have rather than an hypothetical question.

Comment: I think the question is quite clear. How you can wire euros from EUope in dollars in the States with the less fees

Answer (score 2):

A currency broker will give you the closest rate to the interbank rate. Retail banks and money transfer companies take a spread (the difference between the interbank rate and the rate that they charge you) that is significantly higher than a broker. So search for a broker and get quotes for the amount you wish to transfer.

Comment: I use [USForex](https://www.usforex.com/) and am happy with them. There are several others, too.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [TransferWise](https://www.transferwise.com/). 
They offer nice cross currency transfers with really low rates.